# How to check if an object has a particle system or other modifiers

Tags: python, particles, collections

I have a few objects in my scene and I sort them in collections based on the some parameters of the applied particle systems. No problems here. I would also like to check if an object has a particle system applied or something like a collision modifier. How would I go about doing that?

I have tried the len(obj.particles_systems) == 0 as my condition but that didn't work.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modifiers type are given [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.Modifier.html#bpy.types.Modifier.type).

And you can simply test the type you want from that (including `'PARTICLE_SYSTEM'` or `'COLLISION'`).

Here, they are simply printed:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object

for modifier in obj.modifiers:
    print( modifier.type )
```